# A question on discrete sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Suppose for $1 \leq n \leq M$, we have a discrete sequence $a_n = (1 - 2^{n-M}) \gamma^n$, where $M$ is a fixed strictly positive integer, and $\gamma$ is a fixed strictly positive real number such that $\gamma > 1$.

The question is how can we prove or disprove the monotonicity of the sequence $a_n$?

Answer (score 2):

Noting that the formula for $a_n$ makes sense whenever $n$ is any real number, you can use the formula to define a function $A : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $A(n) = a_n$.

Then just take the derivative of your function $A$ with respect to $n$ and from that you should be able to see whether or not it's monotone.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sorry I made a typo and the text is modified now. It seems to me that the monotonicity depends on whether $1 < \gamma < 2$ or $\gamma > 2$. Any idea?

Comment: Then you should just take the derivative and see if the derivative is ever 0.